# Evaluate the following summation involving hyperbolic trigonometry

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Evaluate the following summation where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\cosh(i\pi k)}{(2k-1)\sqrt{(2k+1)\sin\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}+(2k+1)\sqrt{(2k-1)\sin\left(\frac{2k-1}{2}\pi\right)}}$$

Seeing the denominator closely, I strongly believe that the sum telescopes leaving only a few terms to calculate. I tried and tried but couldn't break the expression into two parts. Also even if I succeeded in breaking the expression into two parts, the $\cosh$ term won't let the terms telescope. I also don't know much about hyperbolic trigonometry. Any hints or solution is greatly appreciated.

This is apparently a self made question but I believe that there is a pretty answer to this question because other questions in that pdf also have pretty answers.

Comment: What's the source of the question? Knowing this can give a sense of the level of sophistication needed to answer. ... A note: Multiplying the denominator by its conjugate leaves an expression that reduces nicely to $4 k (4 k^2 - 1) \cos(k\pi)$; even nicely-er, we have $\cos(k\pi) = (-1)^k$.

Comment: @Blue it is from a self made pdf

Comment: And how did you deal with cosh??

Comment: You should state in the body of the question that this is a self-made question, as it may not have a particularly pretty answer. If you have reasons to believe that there is a pretty answer, then also give those reasons. (Knowing what led to this sum may also be helpful.) ... My earlier comment only indicates what happens to the denominator when multiplied by its conjugate; the $\cosh(i\pi k)$ remains in the numerator (which then also has that multiplied conjugate). ... That said, you can use  the relation $\cosh(i\theta)=\cos\theta$ to deal with it.

Comment: Oh ... If by "self-made" you didn't mean you made it *your*self, then that's different. :) Still, some additional context might still be helpful, such as the presumed level of the text, what tools and techniques have been discussed, etc. (A link to the document itself, perhaps?) The more you can say, the better, as this can help answerers avoid explaining things you already understand, or using techniques beyond the intended scope of the question. ... Good luck!

Comment: @Blue use elementary techniques as far as possible (a bit above high school is accepted) but if the question seems to be much difficult then you can use the ultimate techniques to evaluate it (advance mathematics)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There is nothing nice. Computing the sum for $n=10^6$ gives $$-0.222705320837+0.086069452671\, i$$ These numbers are not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $k$ is an integer, the summand is
$$a_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k-1)\sqrt{(-1)^k (2 k+1)} +(2 k+1)\sqrt{(-1)^k (1-2 k)}   }$$ which is
$$a_k=\frac {1}{4k}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(-1)^k}}{\sqrt{2 k+1}}-\frac{\sqrt{(-1)^{k+1}}}{\sqrt{2k-1}} \right)$$
A bit of complex numbers
$$\sqrt{(-1)^k}=\{i,1,i,1,i,1,i,1,i,1,\cdots\}$$
$$\sqrt{(-1)^{k+1}}=\{1,i,1,i,1,i,1,i,1,i,\cdots\}$$ and the first $a_n$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 1 & -\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & \frac{1}{8 \sqrt{5}}-\frac{i}{8 \sqrt{3}} \\
 3 & -\frac{1}{12 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{i}{12 \sqrt{7}} \\
 4 & \frac{1}{48}-\frac{i}{16 \sqrt{7}} \\
 5 & -\frac{1}{60}+\frac{i}{20 \sqrt{11}} \\
 6 & \frac{1}{24 \sqrt{13}}-\frac{i}{24 \sqrt{11}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, use your calculator.